# Using sparql SERVICE between Stardog and Fuseki

Tags: sparql, fuseki, apache-jena, stardog

I am new to Fuseki and Stardog, and I am trying to use a sparql SERVICE query to access some of the information in a Jena Fuseki (2.4.0) server with the Stardog (4.2) interface. The issue I am having is that every query I try ends up with an "*Internal Server Error*". Here is an example:

```
select ?f ?g
WHERE {
  SERVICE <http://localhost:3030/resultados/query> {
    ?f a ?g
  }
}
```

Looking at the http messages sent, I found that Fuseki answers with a 400 code error with the following code:

```
Error 400: Parse error: 
SELECT ?f ?g 
WHERE {
  ?f rdf:type ?g
}

Line 3, column 6: Unresolved prefixed name: rdf:type
```

Which seems to indicate that it doesn't support the rdf prefix. However, if I include it in the query, the error message changes to "*Multiple prefix declarations for prefix 'rdf'*"

Is there some configuration in Fuseki or Stardog that I might be missing to allow these queries? Both are installed with the default settings.

Thanks

Comment: One thing worth trying is to rename the prefix both in the definitions and in the query to something else (e.g. to `rdf2`) and see if it works.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. It seems like Stardog parses the query the same way, because Fuseki receives exactly the same request.

Comment: And as a last resort, does replacing `rdf:type` with `<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>` work?

Comment: Sorry, but no. I don't know how Stardog preprocesses my query, but the same request travels every time. I was using `a` before, but the request always sent `rdf:type` regardless.

Comment: This looks like a bug in Stardog in that they are submitting federated queries using prefix compaction without including the prefix definitions.  The multiple prefix declarations error is probably an interaction with their namespacing feature. I would report this to the Stardog folks and wait for a fix from them.